# DatabaseWrapper cannot be converted to SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, dbflow

I am trying to get writable database using DBFlow using the FlowManager like this `FlowManager.getDatabase(SampleDatabase.NAME).getWritableDatabase()` using DBFlow version `"4.0.0-beta1"` but i get an error `DatabaseWrapper cannot be converted to SQLiteDatabase`. I found an issue on Github [Can't use existing SQLite database](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/902)  but i cant understand what it means. I really need to do this will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `FlowManager.getDatabase(SampleDatabase.NAME).getWritableDatabase()` method does **not** return a SQLiteDatabase object like `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()`. Instead, it will return an instance of `DatabaseWrapper` class.

If you need direct access to the database, you should be able to get the file path to the database file using `FlowManager.getDatabase(SampleDatabase.NAME).getDatabaseFileName()`. Use this path to open your database using the Android API. However, this is definitely not the recommended way of using DBFlow and maybe leads to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: So what is the recommended way

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. All you said was that you need access to a writable database :)

Comment: maybe this can be another solution: `SQLiteDatabase mDb = ((AndroidDatabase) FlowManager.getDatabase(AppDatabase.DB_NAME).getWritableDatabase()).getDatabase();`